# MS sqlserver dump on Hadoop

Tags: sql-server, database, hadoop, etl

I have read only access to mssqlserver, I want to take the full dump of it on Hadoop cluster in every weekend. 
Sqoop utility is one option but apart from it is there any other efficient way to do it?

Comment: What is it about Sqoop that you find _inefficient_?

Comment: I want to check some alternative than this.

Comment: use Spark SQL jdbc to fetch the data, saveAsTextFile to write to Hadoop. Schedule the job using cron.

Comment: Or, dump each table into a local CSV file with `bcp`, compress the CSV as `.gz` or `.bz2`, then push the CSV to Hadoop using `curl` or a similar tool, via the WebHDFS REST API. Less efficient because of the I/O for intermediate file, also because you cannot parallelize the HTTP transfer. Maybe more efficient on the SQL Server side - and that may count if you have only a short batch window to dump the data. Probably more efficient in terms of network bandwidth, especially if your Hadoop cluster is in a cloud somewhere.